# Speeding up RandomVariate with custom probability distribution

Tags: performance-tuning, random, distributions, sampling

I have the defined a custom distribution, which is a Gaussian where the exponent can be any real `n` greater than 0 (set to actually be >0.5 in use), i.e.

```
ProbabilityDistribution[
  (2^(-((2^n*(Abs[x])^n)/FWHM^n))), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Method -> "Normalize"
]
```

Under this normalisation, the part of the Piecewise function I need simplifies down to (when FullSimplify is used):

```
CustomFunction[FWHM_, n_] = 
  ProbabilityDistribution[
    (2^(-1 - 2^n FWHM^-n Abs[x]^n) (2^n FWHM^-n)^(1/n) Log[2]^(1/n))/Gamma[1 + 1/n](*Re[n]>0*),
    {x, -Infinity, Infinity}
  ]
```

I wish to generate N values from this distribution, which I normally would do using `RandomVariate`:

```
RandomVariate[CustomFunction[FWHM, n] /. {FWHM -> 100, n -> 0.5}, 100(*N*)]
```

However I have noticed that for some values for `FWHM` and `n` this is very slow. For example:

```
RandomVariate[
  CustomFunction[FWHM, n] /. {FWHM -> 5235.315151`, n -> 0.534124`},
  1000
]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

takes >70s to run on my PC, whereas other numbers take less than 1s.

Is there any reason for this, or a way to speed up the `RandomVariate`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you see in MMA 12.3.1 on Win10-64. Your last call to `RandomVariate` takes 0.07s on my laptop, which is not particularly performant. It takes roughly 2s to get one million variates. Maybe clear everything and restart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

dist[FWHM_, n_] =
  ProbabilityDistribution[
   (2^(-((2^n*(Abs[x])^n)/FWHM^n))),
   {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
   Method -> "Normalize",
   Assumptions -> {n > 0, FWHM > 0}];

PDF[dist[FWHM, n], x]

(* (2^(-2^n FWHM^-n Abs[x]^n) Log[2]^(1/n))/(FWHM Gamma[1 + 1/n]) *)

CustomFunction[FWHM_?Positive, n_?Positive] := 
    Evaluate@ProbabilityDistribution[
       PDF[dist[FWHM, n], x], 
       {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];

SeedRandom[1234];

(data1 = RandomVariate[CustomFunction[FWHM, n] /. 
      {FWHM -> 100, n -> 0.5}, 1000]); //
 AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.060385, Null} *)

Show[Histogram[data1, Automatic, "PDF"],
 Plot[PDF[CustomFunction[FWHM, n] /.
    {FWHM -> 100, n -> 0.5}, x],
  {x, Min@data1, Max@data1},
  PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Sometimes the data range can be excessive (although the timing is comparable).

```
SeedRandom[1234];

(data2 = RandomVariate[CustomFunction[FWHM, n] /. 
      {FWHM -> 5235.315151`, n -> 0.534124`}, 1000]); // 
 AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.063217, Null} *)

MinMax@data2

(* {-271327., 4.15334*10^8} *)
```

Using a different seed

```
SeedRandom[123];

(data3 = RandomVariate[CustomFunction[FWHM, n] /. 
      {FWHM -> 5235.315151`, n -> 0.534124`}, 1000]); // 
 AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.061821, Null} *)

MinMax@data3

(* {-245766., 356148.} *)

Show[Histogram[data3, Automatic, "PDF"],
 Plot[PDF[CustomFunction[FWHM, n] /.
    {FWHM -> 5235.315151`, n -> 0.534124`}, x],
  {x, Min@data3, Max@data3},
  PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, seems to speed it up. Is there a reason why embedding within ```Evaluate@ProbabilityDistribution[PDF[dist[FWHM, n], x],]```  helps speed things up?

Comment: The revised `CustomFunction` restricts its arguments to being numeric (`Positive`) so it never tries to evaluate symbolically. Because of the argument restrictions, it must be defined with `SetDelayed` rather than `Set` and the `Evaluate` is necessary to do the one-time evaluation of  `PDF[dist[FWHM, n], x]`.